# Random colors in pyplot.scatter based on value

Tags: python, matplotlib, colors, cluster-analysis, scatter-plot

I have a large pandas dataframe that I clustered and the cluster id is stored in a column of a dataframe.
I would like to display clusters in such a way that each cluster has a different color.
I tried doing this with a colormap but the problem is that I have too many points and clusters so nearby clusters get assign only slightly different colors, so when I plot all of them I just get a big mashup that looks like this:

[image]

Note that this is image contains about 4000 clusters, but because colors of clusters are just assigned top to bottom, nearby clusters blend together.

I would like nearby clusters to be painted in different colors so I tried making a random color for each cluster and then assign each point a color based on its cluster label like this:

```
# creating a color for each distinct cluster label
colors = [(random.random(), random.random(), random.random())
          for _ in range(len(set(data['labels'])))]
# assigning color to a point based on its cluster label
for index, row in data.iterrows():
    plt.scatter(row['x'], row['y'], color=colors[int(row['labels'])])
```

Now this program works but it is *much* slower that vectorized version above.

Is there a way to do color each cluster in clearly different colors without writing a for loop?

Comment: Are you sure a map with 4000 clusters is even readable? In any case, you have to develop a code to ensure that neighboring clusters do not have the same color. I would not know what topological approach can guarantee that.

Comment: @Mr.T I agree on that, but first shuffling those colours would already make it much more readable

Comment: @Mr.T That is a good point, I am trying to fine-tune the clustering hyperparameters and ideally lower the number of clusters, and visualization would greatly help me to see if I am on the right track.

Comment: I think endive's answer is then what you are looking for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This creates a random colormap of 256 colors that you can then pass to scatter :

```
def segmentation_cmap():
    vals = np.linspace(0, 1, 256)
    np.random.shuffle(vals)
    return plt.cm.colors.ListedColormap(plt.cm.CMRmap(vals))


ax.scatter(row['x'],row['y'],c=row['labels'],s=1,cmap=segmentation_cmap())
```

You may add colors, but you would have trouble seeing the differences anyways at some point !

Comment: This works perfectly, as I would like just to get the general idea about where the algorithm separates the clusters so I can guarantee the clustering algorithm works. Thanks